# xlsxwriter: how to center image in cell

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Im setting the size of my column and rows using set_column and set_row respectively, like so:

```
my_worksheet.set_column('A:KK', 17)
my_worksheet.set_row(0, 99.6)
```

I have this code to print an image of arbitrary size to the cell:

```
width, height = im.size
# Calculate scale: Problematic
x_scale = IMAGE_CELL_SIZE_PX[0]/float(width) 
y_scale = (IMAGE_CELL_SIZE_PX[1] - 5.0)/float(height)
# Calculate offset: Problematic
x_offset = ((IMAGE_CELL_SIZE_PX[0] - width) / 2.0) / x_scale
y_offset = ((IMAGE_CELL_SIZE_PX[1] - 5 - height) / 2.0) / y_scale
worksheet.insert_image(row, col, image_path, {'x_offset': x_offset, 'y_offset': y_offset, 'x_scale': x_scale, 'y_scale': y_scale})
```

problem is it doesnt work. The image size is wrong and the pictures are most of the time far from centered. It's like Im missing a term. **The main issue is that I cannot find a way to convert from pixels to Excel's and xlsxwriter length unit robustly in a machine independent way.**

I can only set the width of the cells through set_column which takes excel units and I know the image dimensions in pixels (from Pillow Image.size). Apparently the transformation between the two is machine dependent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `worksheet._size_col()` and `worksheet._size_row()` ([see here in the code](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py#L4280)) which converts a column or row zero-based index to a pixel size.

The other thing to look out for is that Excel scales images based on a DPI of 96. If the image has another DPI you should account for the scaling. This is what happens [internally](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py#L3977) in XlsxWriter to account for Excel's scaling:

```
    # Scale by non 96dpi resolutions.
    width *= 96.0 / x_dpi
    height *= 96.0 / y_dpi
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell dimensions with

```
worksheet_set_row_pixels
worksheet_set_column_pixels
```

The image has to have the DPI 96/96

```
lxw_image_options options = { column_pixels/2-image_width/2, row_pixels/2-image_height/2, 1, 1, 2 };
  
worksheet_insert_image_opt(worksheet, 0, 0, "image.png", &options);
```